# How to make racket web server never timeout?

Tags: scheme, racket

is there any way to specify that server-side never times out in Racket web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you [specify a timeout](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/servlet.html#%28part._timeouts%29) of `0`?

If that's not an option or doesn't work you can set the timeout for some unreasonably large number such as `31536000` - the number of seconds in a year, or 30 days, or whatever is going to be more long lived than the server is likely to be in your case.

That being said, it would be very strange to have a timeout that's either effectively or actually infinite. At some point, all servers generally need to give up and assume the client is never coming back. It's the healthy thing to do. Otherwise the server will just sit there sad, dejected, quietly logging, "Why didn't they ever come back?! Did I not serve their needs adequately? I live only to serve - it is in my name!"

...on on a more serious note, it can lead to what looks like a memory leak when you have open connections with no timeout just sitting out there, slowly accumulating resources (memory) over time. In many such cases you have to restart the server app to get those resources released.

Comment: Thanks!..tried this out(never used this thing before)...You have explained your point well, and I think I understand. I just have a server app that has its thread doing an expensive task, and when the result is back, the web page's refresh button is supposed to pull the result out, but if the server timed out, user gets nothing~~So that's why I want longer timeout time or never times out..but due to the problem you pointed out, I think I will just make it one hour time, Is one hour still too long????

Comment: That's up to you, but I think 1 hour is *much* more reasonable than infinite timeouts. I've been known to have 1 hour timeouts on servers that allow, for example, large file uploads. Sometimes there are necessities in life we can't compromise on.

Comment: OK.Great! Oh, one last question, is the number specified calculated in million second? (didn't find it in documentation...)

Comment: The link I gave appears to take an input in seconds (not fractions of a second) - so if you give it `5` it will be 5 **seconds**, as opposed to 5 **milliseconds** or **nanoseconds** as is common in many other places in code (such as sleeping a thread for some amount of time). At least, that's the way I read the docs.